One hover to trigger another hover in the same div
I have an aeroplane and two propellers
I want to spin both propellers on hover, I can do it separately, but not together. Basically I want to hover one propeller (or the plane) and trigger the hover for the other propeller as well. Is this possible?
div.slide-right {
  width:100%;
}
div.slide-right div.inner {
  animation: slide-right 5s;
  margin-left:18%;
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 18%;
  }
}
div.slide-right:hover img ??????????

So if I can trigger the hovers using the div.slide-right:hover what syntax is necessary?


  a#rotator6 {
  margin-left: 332px;
  margin-top: 53px;
  position: absolute;
}

a#rotator6 img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

a#rotator6 img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  transform: translate();
  a#rotator5 {
    margin-left: 507px;
    margin-top: 53px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  a#rotator5 img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 60px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
  }
  a#rotator5 img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(1440deg);
    transform: translate();
  }
<div class="slide-right">
  <a id="rotator6"><img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/propeller-screw-2848202-2368700.png" /></a>
  <a id="rotator5"><img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/propeller-screw-2848202-2368700.png" /></a>
</div>




In your shown example, none of the two propellors appear to be rotating, but instead the element with the image named noprop.png is ...? (But hard to tell what is what, when you don't provide the actual images.)

I made you a snippet. I removed the noprop since it is not used and confuses. We want a [mcve]

@CBroe noprop is the plane, both prop.png spin fine, but I want them to spin together not separately on hover

Instead of using #rotator5:hover and #rotator6:hover, describe what is happening when the parent gets hovered:
div:hover #rotator5, div:hover #rotator6.

You can either do this by applying :hover on a common parent element; so if stuff should rotate here, as soon as .slide-right gets hovered anywhere, you could simply use that, .slide-right:hover img - or wrap the two propellors into an additional element. If you don't want that, then you could still use :has() to "check" if one of the images inside the parents is gettin hovered.

@CBroe I'm a bit lost, I added the CSS for the slide-right, but don't know how to use the snippet gadget

Click [edit], then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and paste int the CSS frame

@mplungjan it refuses the edit saying my post is mostly code

That is harsh. Do you want to REPLACE the CSS or add to it

@mplungjan neither really. I want to know what to put in div.slide-right:hover img

Then what you have now is fine

@CBroe thanks man, I worked it out. Do you want to put an answer I can upvote?

You can either do this by applying :hover on a common parent element; so if stuff should rotate here, as soon as .slide-right gets hovered anywhere, you could simply use that, .slide-right:hover img - or wrap the two propellors into an additional element.
If you don't want that, then you could still use :has() to "check" if one of the images inside the parents is getting hovered.

If you're okay with using some JavaScript, and a few changes to your HTML, here's how you can do it:


"use strict";

const rotator5 = document.getElementById("rotator5");
const rotator6 = document.getElementById("rotator6");

const rotators = [rotator5, rotator6];
const propellers = document.querySelectorAll(".prop-img");

rotators.forEach(function (rot) {
  rot.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    propellers.forEach((prop) => prop.classList.add("rotate-prop"));
  });
  rot.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    propellers.forEach((prop) => prop.classList.remove("rotate-prop"));
  });
});
a#rotator6 {
  margin-left: 332px;
  margin-top: 53px;
  position: absolute;
}

a#rotator6 img,
a#rotator5 img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.rotate-prop {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  transform: translate();
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slide-right">
        <a id="rotator6"><img
                src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/propeller-screw-2848202-2368700.png"
                class="prop-img" /></a>
        <a id="rotator5"><img
                src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/propeller-screw-2848202-2368700.png"
                class="prop-img" /></a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>



